# Is it possible to convert this curl command to PHP?

Tags: php, curl

Is it possible to convert this curl command to PHP?

```
curl -F file=@filename https://any.website.com/
```

Comment: https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

Answer (score 0):

Try With:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://any.website.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: It did not work